# Javascript doesn't get loaded on second visit (phonegap)

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

On my phonegap app when I login I redirect to a page with window.location.href and it works fine. But when I go to another page from there and return to that page using a link

```
<li><a href="menu.html">Chat Rooms</a></li>
```

it doesn't load any of the javascript. I even set an alert message with setInterval to see if it's the loading. But it just doesn't load any javascript at all.

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    function onDeviceReady() {
        // Now safe to use the PhoneGap API
    }

    var username = window.localStorage["username"];
    var password = window.localStorage["password"];
    loginRedirect(username, password);

    getRooms("chatrooms");
});
```

Comment: are you sure your checking for the ready state ? http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_events_events.md.html

Comment: I added the javascipt to it. I didn't even use phonegap functions so that shouldn't matter right?

Comment: I am also using jquerymobile in it.

Comment: I just played with phonegap around a year back, then switched to IOS outsourcing!, hopefully a more experienced guy will be able to help you :)

Comment: It started working when I added rel="external" in it.

Answer (score 1):

After putting rel = "external" in the a tag it started working.

```
<a href="index.html" rel="external">External Link</a>
```

Comment: That's true! but you loose the slide effect on page transition(if you're using it). this should be used when you want to refer a external domain.